# When Wi-Fi is enabled on my Windows 10 PC, my bluetooth headphones don't work properly

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, bluetooth, headphones, interference

So I have been having this problem since I got my new Pre-Built PC and I can't find a single working solution to it.

I have not been able to use my Bluetooth headphones that worked on my previous computer and still works on all my other devices on the new PC I got about a month ago. The sound would cut in and out and get out of sync. I eventually figured out that when I turn my Wi-Fi off, the problem disappears. So great, I found a way to make my headphones work again but at the costs of not being able to use the internet. What good is that?

Is there any fix for this or am I just stuck with this problem until I give up and buy wired headphones?

Also, a common solution I have seen is to use 5G Wi-Fi instead of 2G. The problem is I was using 5G the entire time and still had this problem, so im not sure whats going on

Comment: Are you using any wireless keyboard/mouse style peripherals? Some of them are also on the 2.4ghz band...

Comment: No, both my mouse and keyboard are wired. The headphones were the only thing connected

Comment: Bluetooth and Wifi are both at 2.4GHz, you can try moving the Bluetooth adapter on a different usb port.

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean. I'm not using a USB adapter, the Bluetooth came built into the PC

Comment: You say it's a Pre-Built, what are the details of the machine? Make/Model? Hardware details are helpful in diagnosis.

Comment: You PC probably uses a combined bluetooth/WiFi module and antenna. Buying a new USB Bluetooth module would probably fix this. You should then disable your old one before installing the new USB one.